# Website with 2 different sections, user picks and cookie remembers choice

Tags: javascript, cookies, location, country

Looking for a code example similar to http://www.trafalgar.com/ where the user is *asked* to pick a location and the cookie is stored and user is automatically taking to that particular page when they next visit. Have been searching for many hours (days) now but no joy, assumed there would be loads of examples, any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the time you'd handle that server side so that it'd work on clients that don't have JavaScript enabled. It'd also be faster because rather than fetching the full page, CSS, JS and images, parsing it, etc and finally running the JavaScript which would then redirect the browser to a new URL, the server would just send back the redirect right away—or build a different page dynamically.

Looks like that's what the domain you're looking at does.